# AudioTrack: Playing sound coming in over WiFi

Tags: android, audio

I've got an AudioTrack in my application, which is set to Stream mode. I want to write audio which I receive over a wireless connection. The AudioTrack is declared like this:

```
mPlayer = new AudioTrack(STREAM_TYPE,
                         FREQUENCY,
                         CHANNEL_CONFIG_OUT,
                         AUDIO_ENCODING,
                         PLAYER_CAPACITY,
                         PLAY_MODE);
```

Where the parameters are defined like:

```
private static final int FREQUENCY = 8000,
                         CHANNEL_CONFIG_OUT = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                         AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                         PLAYER_CAPACITY = 2048,
                         STREAM_TYPE = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                         PLAY_MODE = AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM;
```

However, when I write data to the AudioTrack with write(), it will play choppy... The call

```
byte[] audio = packet.getData();
mPlayer.write(audio, 0, audio.length);
```

is made whenever a packet is received over the network connection. Does anybody have an idea on why it sounds choppy? Maybe it has something to do with the WiFi connection itself? I don't think so, as the sound doesn't sound horrible the other way around, when I send data from the Android phone to another source over UDP. The sound then sounds complete and not choppy at all... So does anybody have an idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried playing with `PLAYER_CAPACITY`? I believe you should use `getMinBufferSize()` to get the proper value, as shown here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

Comment: I've tried that... But the data I get from the Network is usually less than the 4096 I (currently) get on this device from getMinBufferSize. Setting it to buffersize < receivedBytes results in no audio being played at all... The amount of bytes I receive range from 900 to 2048 (depending on source, other mobile device or pc).

Comment: I had a second look on this, in my case, the choppy is due to significant amount of packet missing/retransmitting. In some resource-limited system like Android, the program must process each individual UDP packet fast enough in order to prevent packet missing.

Answer (score 7):

Do you know how many bytes per second you are recieving, the average time between packets compares, and the maximum time between packets? If not, can you add code to calculate it?

You need to be averaging 8000 samples/second * 2 bytes/sample = **16,000  bytes per second** in order to keep the stream filled.

A gap of more than 2048 bytes / (16000 bytes/second) = **128 milliseconds** between incoming packets will cause your stream to run dry and the audio to stutter.

One way to prevent it is to *increase* the buffer size (PLAYER_CAPACITY).   A larger buffer will be more able to handle variation in the incoming packet size and rate.  The cost of the extra stability is a larger delay in starting playback while you wait for the buffer to initially fill.

Comment: On a rough estimate I get about 67,200 bytes per second. About (roughly) 70 packages worth of 960 bytes. I say roughly because this is via a wired connection. When I go through wireless, I guess I'll receive about 50 (maybe a little more, maybe a little less) packages a second, giving me 48,000 bytes per second. I'd say that's about enough to keep it filled. :o

Comment: After some debugging and looking through several logcats, I've come to notice that it is an "obtainBuffer timed out" bug... Im still trying to fix it though...

Comment: Did you ever solved this problem ? Please post the updates. I also have a similar problem.... thanks!!!

Comment: I ended up using the OpenSL ES audio API. It is with in the NDK development kit. It's more low level, but it is a bit better than the Java API's in my opinion...

Comment: @ThaMe90, How good is OpenSL ES for solving the choppy, can you post some feedback?

Comment: Well, for one, you have so much more control when compared to AudioTrack. Keep in mind though, that this was over 2 years ago. Since then, things might (and should) have improved. But I don't know that for sure, as I haven't been working on this piece of code for 1.5 years. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed so far AFAIK, this choppy issue make AudioTrack useless when dealing with music streaming. I read from other website saying this is caused by frequently inefficient data transferring between Java and Native layer, resulting data packet feed slower than audio play.

Answer (score 5):

I have partially solved it by placing the `mPlayer.write(audio, 0, audio.length);` in it's own `Thread`. This does take away some of the choppy-ness (due to the fact that write is a blocking call), but it still sounds choppy after a good second or 2. It still has a significant delay of 2-3 seconds.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        byte[] audio = packet.getData();
        mPlayer.write(audio, 0, audio.length);
    }
}.start();
```

Just a little anonymous `Thread` that does the writing now...

Anybody have an idea on how to solve this issue?

---

Edit:

After some further checking and debugging, I've noticed that this is an issue with obtainBuffer.
I've looked at the [java code of the AudioTrack](http://hi-android.info/src/android/media/AudioTrack.java.html) and the [C++ code of AudioTrack](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp) And I've noticed that it only can appear in the C++ code.

```
if (__builtin_expect(result!=NO_ERROR, false)) {
    LOGW(   "obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) "
            "user=%08x, server=%08x", u, s);
    mAudioTrack->start(); // FIXME: Wake up audioflinger
    timeout = 1;
}
```

I've noticed that there is a `FIXME` in this piece of code. :< But anyway, could anybody explain how this C++ code works? I've had some experience with it, but it was never as complicated as this...

---

Edit 2:

I've tried somewhat different now, the difference being that I buffer the data I receive, and then when the buffer is filled with some data, it is being written to the player. However, the player keeps up with consuming for a few cycles, then the `obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?)` warning kicks in, and there is no data at all written to the player untill it is kick started back to life... After that, it will continually get data written to it untill the buffer is emptied.

Another slight difference is that I stream a file to the player now. That is, reading it in chunks, the writing those chunks to the buffer. This simulates the packages being received over wifi...

I am beginning to wonder if this is just an OS issue that Android has, and it isn't something I can solve on my own... Anybody got any ideas on that?

---

Edit 3:

I've done more testing, but this doesn't help me any further. This test shows me that I only get lag when I try to write to the AudioTrack for the first time. This takes somewhat between 1 and 3 seconds to complete. I did this by using the following bit of code:

```
long beforeTime = Utilities.getCurrentTimeMillis(), afterTime = 0;
mPlayer.write(data, 0, data.length);
afterTime = Utilities.getCurrentTimeMillis();
Log.e("WriteToPlayerThread", "Writing a package took " + (afterTime - beforeTime) + " milliseconds");
```

However, I get the following results:
[Logcat Image http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/3453/logcatimage.png](http://img810.imageshack.us/img810/3453/logcatimage.png)

These show that the lag initially occurs at the beginning, after which the AudioTrack keeps getting data continuously... I really need to get this one fixed...

Comment: The __builtin_expect is an optimization hint. The logic boils down to "if error, then wite to log, call start() on the audiotrack, and set the timeout flag." `result` is being set in the previous line, `result = cblk->cv.waitRelative(cblk->lock, seconds(1));`, which seems to be a wait on a condition variable. So it appears that there is something wrong with the thread-saftey scheme.

Comment: Further evidence of a thread-saftey bug in this code is this line from later in the same function: `    LOGW_IF(timeout, "*** SERIOUS WARNING *** obtainBuffer() timed out but didn't need to be locked. We recovered, but this shouldn't happen (user=%08x, server=%08x)", u, s);`