# Playing audio from network on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, naudio

Is it possible to play audio on Xamarin.Forms (Android only, no iOS required) which is received from network over TCP or UDP? In WPF, I'm using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) and I have something like this:

```
// set output device
var provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(codec.RecordFormat);
outputDevice = new WaveOut();
outputDevice.DeviceNumber = 0;
outputDevice.Init(provider);
outputDevice.Play();
```

Data is received from TCP connection:

```
if (outputDevice != null)
{
   byte[] decoded = codec.Decode(data, 0, data.Length);
   provider.AddSamples(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
}
```

In this case, `data` is `byte[]` - its added to circular buffer and WaveOut handles it like stream, playing it continously. That solution works great.

I need same thing in Xamarin - I guess I need some kind of wrapper around [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) since it [apparently supports playing from byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297923/audiotrack-playing-sound-coming-in-over-wifi). How should I do this, what is the "best" or preferred way? Basically, how to play streamed audio received over pure TCP/UDP socket?

Answer (score 1):

Google's Android `ExoPlayer` can stream that media format properly.

The following code is a really simple example of ExoPlayer, but it will show you that it does play that stream:

```
var mediaUrl = "http://api-streaming.youscribe.com/v1/products/2919465/documents/3214936/audio/stream";
var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mediaUrl);

var userAgent = Util.GetUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerDemo");
var defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
var defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
var extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, defaultDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
var defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
var adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
var defaultTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(this, defaultTrackSelector);
exoPlayer.Prepare(extractorMediaSource);
exoPlayer.PlayWhenReady = true;
```

**Note:**

1.exoPlayer is a class-level variable of SimpleExoPlayer type;

2.this is using the Xamarin.Android binding libraries from the [Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer/) package

**ExoPlayer Docs:**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer